# Declaring an array with const keyword Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, constants, immutability, mutability

I have created an array - `const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];` 
Now if I try to reassign values at specific indexes, it works like - `cars[0] = "Toyota"; cars[1] = "Honda"; cars[2] = "Hyundai";`
but when I try to reassign it at single time like `cars = ["Toyota" , "Honda" , "Hyundai"]` , it throws an error. I am not able to understand the mutability vs reassigning concept here.

Comment: Did you read the MDN doc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const str = 'abcd';
str = 'changed'; //error


const list = [1,2,3]; // Assume this array is created on memory loc 0x001 (imaginary)

list[0] = 200; // no error  here the memory location remains constant but the content changes.

list = [6,4,2]; // error Here new assignment hence memory location changes so error
```

Arrays or objects are mapped by location and not value compared to strings/numbers.

Answer (score 0):

> The keyword const is a little misleading.
>   It does NOT define a constant value. It defines a constant reference to a value.
>   Because of this, we cannot change constant primitive values, but we can change the properties of constant objects.

read more: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_const.asp

once const is declared it can only point to that specific data, you can change things within this data but you can't tell it to point elsewhere.

When you declare the variable as const it assigns it a place in memory and says "you may only look here for data!" it does not say "this is the only data you can read", thus you can change the data in that location but you can not give it a whole new set of data as this would exist somewhere else in memory.

Answer (score 0):

When you are assigning to variable `cars` you are basically trying to change it's reference which violates `const` but when you are trying to modify a value(example `cars[0]='some value'`) in `cars` it's reference is still the same, value is changed, you need to understand that reference of object `cars` still remains same.